# how to execute the 'net use' command from the c++ code by system() method in visula studio 2012?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, cmd, system

i use the following way to execute it

```
system("net use * /del /yes");
```

but it gives the following

```
`'net' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`
```

but when i run the same command on the `CMD` it is executed successfully. as

```
You have these remote connections:

    Z:              \\x.x.x.x\x
Continuing will cancel the connections.

The command completed successfully.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was of `Environment Path` add the Path `"C:\Windows\System32"` then it will execute properly and give the output correctly.